# less than relation between two natural numbers

Tags: coq

Successor of one natural number is less than Successor of second natural number.I have less than relation between numbers also. On contradiction basis (H1&H2), I can close the goal? Secondly I have following hypothesis(H3), just want to consider right side of H3 as new hypothesis H4 . Thank you for help.

```
 Q1: 
 H1: S i2 < S i1.
 H2: i1 < i2

 Q2:
 H3: Z2<Z1 \/ (i2>i1)
 H4: (i2>i1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time a goal like your Q1 can be solved automatically by `lia`.  Here is an example.

```
Require Import Arith Lia.

Lemma Q1 (A : Prop) (i1 i2 : nat)
(H1: S i2 < S i1)
(H2: i1 < i2) : A.
Proof.
intros.
lia.
Qed.
```

Your Q2 does not seem to be a correct Coq situation.  Hypothesis `H3` does not respect Coq typing constraints, you need to re-phrase it.

Comment: When I asserted Q1 in the code unknown A (error message).Therefore I want to write Q1 in this form of lemma(so that lemma can be asserted in the code). Lemma Q1 forall(A : Prop) (i1 i2 : nat), (S i2 < S i1)-> ( i1 < i2) -> A. Proof. intros. lia. Qed Q2:Command for considering right side of hypothesis as new hypothesis. –

Comment: Your initial question was not a complete goal, so I needed to add some proposition for it `A` here, but the fragment of text that I gave you does work in Coq (I checked it).  You had an error message only because you took a fragment of my answer.  Try to ask questions that are more complete, whose text is correct Coq code, and when you receive answers, try to respect their entire content, please.  The fragment of code that you inserted in your comment is also not correct Coq code.

Comment: you write Q2: Command for ....  This sentence is too confusing, please rephase it.